# split string using regex python and "re" package

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm using `Python 3` on Windows 10.  Consider the following string:

```
import re
s = ["12345", "67891", "01112"]
```

I want to split these zips at the 3 character to get the zip3, but this code throws an error.

```
re.split("\d{3}", s)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

I'm not quite sure how to get around.  Help appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `s` is a list of strings, not a string.

Comment: what should be the result?  `["123","45","678","91","011","12"]` ? - Why regex?

Comment: Yes the result should be the first 3 char of the string.  I'm using regex because `str.split` doesn't take char counts as far as I know?  If you know of better methods please advise.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew do i need an iteration?  `R` does this flawlessly without iteration, so I figure `python` would be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first three of each, simply string-slice them:

```
s = ["12345", "67891", "01112"]
first_tree = [p[0:3] for p in  s] 
print(first_tree)
```

Outtput:

```
['123', '678', '011'] # slicing
```

---

To split all text in threes, join it, then use chunking to get chunks of 3 letters:

```
s = ["12345", "67891", "01112"]
k = ''.join(s)
threesome = [k[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(k),3)]
print(threesome)
```

Outtput:

```
['123', '456', '789', '101', '112']  # join + chunking
```

See [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks) and [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Slicing and chunking works on strings as well - the official doku about strings is here: [about strings and slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html?highlight=string%20slice#strings)

---

To get the remainder as well:

```
s = ["12345", "67891", "01112"]
three_and_two = [[p[:3], p[3:]] for p in s] 
print(three_and_two) #  [['123', '45'], ['678', '91'], ['011', '12']]
```